# Are the Drivers and Controllers in Orchard somewhat the same?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions, orchardcms

I'm creating a new widget in the Orchard CMS. The way I do this is by adding a Route and Controller first and try out the functionality by running the code on an url defined in the Route, like `http://localhost:30320/Index`
My Routes.cs is set up so it routes this request to the specified controller and stuff is happening on the screen. This all works quite well.

Now that I'm happy with the result I tried placing all of this in a new Widget. For this I've created new Migrations class which sets up the widget. This is fairly straightforward and now the widget has been added to the Homepage layer.

The thing I'm running into is the Controller isn't executed anymore. Not very strange as I haven't set up any routes which specify the Controller should be executed. I'm wondering, should I move the Controller logic to the Driver method, so the View still gets the necessary information?

The driver I've got at the moment looks like this:

```
public class FrontpageDrivers : ContentPartDriver<FrontpageModelPart>
{
    protected override DriverResult Display(FrontpageModelPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        //return base.Display(part, displayType, shapeHelper);
        if (displayType.StartsWith("Detail"))
            return ContentShape("Parts_Index", () => shapeHelper.Parts_Index(
                                                                    LatestPostCollection: part.LatestPostCollection,
                                                                    TopRatedPostCollection: part.TopRatedPostCollection,
                                                                    TotalMonthCollection: part.TotalMonthCollection,
                                                                    ContentPart: part
                                                                    ));
        return null;
    }
}
```

The PartsController method which needs to be executed looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Detail()
{
    //Do something to get blogposts
    var getter = new GetBlogPost(_blogService, _blogPostService, _votingService);
    getter.Initialize();

    var latestPosts = getter.GetLatestPosts();
    var highestRankedPosts = getter.GetHighestRankedPosts();
    var archiveData = getter.GetTotalPostsPerMonth();

    var viewModel = new FrontpageModelPart();
    viewModel.LatestPostCollection = latestPosts;
    viewModel.TopRatedPostCollection = highestRankedPosts;
    viewModel.TotalMonthCollection = archiveData;

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

I've tried renaming the method to Index and Detail, both won't do the trick. 
The view which is shown is `/Views/Parts/Index.cshtml`. If I put some static text in the file, I can see this view is being rendered correctly.

So, should I move the Controller logic to the Driver, or am I forgetting something in the setup?

Note: I've got the placement, module, migrations and handler in place already.

**Edit**:
If I'm using this code, everything works quite well:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(FrontpageModelPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    var controller = new PartsController(Services, _blogService, _blogPostService, _votingService);
    part = controller.GetIndexViewModel();

    if (displayType.StartsWith("Detail"))
        return ContentShape("Parts_Index", () => shapeHelper.Parts_Index(
                                                                LatestPostCollection: part.LatestPostCollection,
                                                                TopRatedPostCollection: part.TopRatedPostCollection,
                                                                TotalMonthCollection: part.TotalMonthCollection,
                                                                ContentPart: part
                                                                ));
    return null;
}
```

Even though this works quite well, it just feels like 'hacking' to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use controllers when you want to take over everything that appears in the Content zone, but return a shape result so that the theme, widgets, etc can still chime in. That's what your controller fails to do.